# Firefox Australis Theme: Place address bar at bottom

Tags: firefox

With the new **Australis** design of Firefox 29, there is now a new address bar. I used to put my address bar and the search bar together with all the button to the bottom of the window. I also have my tabs showing at the bottom.

Now with the new **Australis** theme I could not find a way to move the address bar to the bottom. Is it possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker recommended that [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) could be used to add a toolbar to the bottom of the screen, and that the Address Bar could be moved to that toolbar.

To move the Address Bar to the bottom:

1. Right click any toolbar and select `Customize...`
2. If there does not exist a toolbar at the bottom of the screen, then drag any toolbar **other than that which holds the Address Bar** to the bottom of the screen.
3. Move the mouse onto the Address Bar and wait for it to turn into a Hand icon.
4. Left click and drag the Address Bar onto the toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I have now installed the extension and it is terrific, it includes all kinds of missing options such as button size, location, tab style, etc. This extension brings us back to the time before Firefox 3.6 when the browser really was _ours_ to customize! Thank you to lanoxx for askng the question and getting me interested!

Comment: The extension fixes some issues, yet I still cant get the tabs on bottom. They're on top, driving me furious. Why does Firefox have to piss me off every 3 months?

Comment: Please, could you add a screenshot how should we do this? (btw, I don't have enough reputation to downvote - so I'm not alone confused with your answer)

Comment: I have edited the answer with detailed instructions. I hope that it helps!